telebot does send messages with delay
I wrote the code using the telebot library. The problem is that after the printing animation ends and before the message is printed there is a rather impressive delay.
@bot.message_handler(func=content_check)
def ai_content(message):
    text = message.text
    bot.send_chat_action(message.chat.id, 'typing')
    chat_response = client.chat.complete(
        model = model,
        messages = [
            {
                "role": "system",
                "content": 'Напиши краткое содержание книги.',
            },
            {
                "role": "user",
                "content": text,
            }
        ]
    )
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, chat_response.choices[0].message.content)

I tried to find some other way to send messages faster but didn't find anything.
